# Is there a maximum value for the volume depth of a render texture?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, direct3d

I'm using render texture as an array of textures by specifying the size of the array in [volume depth](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture-volumeDepth.html) property. But, sometimes when I exceed some value (eg. for 128x128 textures it's 45...) it return me an error : `D3D11: Failed to create RenderTexture (128 x 128 fmt 39 aa 1), error 0x80070057` which isn't very clear. Therefore, I supposed it's because this property has a maximum value ? But I did not find it in unity manual either on internet.

Does anyone know this value or could tell me where I could find it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width, height, and depth must be equal to or less than `D3D11_REQ_TEXTURE3D_U_V_OR_W_DIMENSION` (2048).

Likely you are having issues with some other parameter. Try enabling the Direct3D Debug Device for better information. Use `-force-d3d11-debug`. With Windows 10 or Windows 11, you have to install it by enabling the Windows optional feature *Graphics Tools*.

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-devices-downlevel-intro).

Comment: thanks for the answer, microsoft's explanations seem a bit dubious (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/ns-d3d11-d3d11_texture3d_desc). Because I can make texture larger than 2048... But in you link they talk about 16384 for width and height dimension and 2048 for depth which seems more likely to me.